# How to autofill 0(zero) at the back after the decimal point in jquery?

Tags: jquery, regex

How to autofill 0(zero) at the back after the decimal point in jquery? Like if user insert not enough digit then it will auto fill with zero(0) at the back.

**Example:
User Insert - 0.12345
Then it must add to - 0.12345000**

**What I have tried:**

This is what I try but I just know how to set the dot symbol can insert only once in the text field.

```
$("#Lat").on("keypress keyup blur",function (event) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
           if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
               event.preventDefault();
           }
       });

$("#Lng").on("keypress keyup blur",function (event) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
           if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
               event.preventDefault();
           }
       });
```

Comment: That seems a bit complicated, why not just use `toFixed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `toFixed(n)` and you can use `blur` or `change` event instead of `keyup` as user may find it troublesome while entering values when it keep on changing for each input

```js
$(function(){
  var specialKeys = new Array();
  specialKeys.push(46); // allow dot which has keyCode = 46 in specialKeys

  $("#Lat,#Lng").on("blur change",function (event) {
    $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val() || 0).toFixed(8));
  });

  //on keypress you can restrict only number and some special characters
  $("#Lat,#Lng").on("keypress", function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
    return ret;
  });
   
  // restrict copy paste
  $("#Lat,#Lng").on("paste drop", function (e) {
      return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Lat">
<input id="Lng">
```

Comment: Its for gps coordinate i don't think thats a good idea for it.

Comment: But this fullfill your requirement of "User Insert - 0.12345 Then it must add to - 0.12345000". If you enter 0.12345 then it is converting it to 0.12345000

Comment: Oh It works thank you so much. But what if I don't allow user to insert alphabet and special character except dot ? How do I add in?

Comment: Please check my updated answer where i have restricted alphabets and special characters except dot

Comment: happy to help you :). You can accept and upvote this answer if find useful